# Can't create a client only collection in meteor using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, coffeescript

Hi I need to create a client side collection, Im using CoffeeScript, Im trying to create it like this:

```
Template.mcqQuestionOptionsFieldset.onCreated ->
  @AddMcqOptions = new Mongo.Collection null
```

when I run the application it does not work, I get the error:

ReferenceError: AddMcqOptions is not defined

I tried without the '@' symbol I tried everything, and in the javascript console I can't see it is loaded, it seems the colleciton does not exists...

If I remove the @ symbol the error path moves to other files Im trying to use the variable but If I add the @ the error path shows up in the same file I declared the variable, can someone tell me what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to declare a global collection, or isolate it to the template? The latter is what your code indicates, but you'll have to access it in a very spcific way.

Comment: this question would be so much easier with normal javascript :(

Comment: The problem is that CS doesn't do a "normal" global variable even when you use `@`. It simply binds the variable to `this`, whatever `this` is (in your case, the template, as @David Weldon mentions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client collection doesn't need to be defined in your template, especially if you're using it in other files.

Just add a file, for example `client/collections.coffee`:

```
@AddMcqOptions = new Mongo.Collection null
```

then use `AddMcqOptions.insert(...)` etc. as normal anywhere on the client.

If you want to keep the current structure, it may also be possible to use the fat arrow (I haven't tested it though). You'd also lose access to `this` / `@` in reference to the template.

```
Template.mcqQuestionOptionsFieldset.onCreated =>
  @AddMcqOptions = new Mongo.Collection null
```

Another possible option which allows you to use `this` / `@` as normal:

```
self = this
Template.mcqQuestionOptionsFieldset.onCreated ->
  self.AddMcqOptions = new Mongo.Collection null
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Template specific Client Collection You can try like this. I am using like this and its working fine:

```
Template.myTemplate.created = function () {
    var instance = this;
    instance._MyClientCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);

    instance._MyClientCollection.insert({...});
}

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    options: function () {
        return Template.instance()._MyClientCollection.find({...}, {sort: {...}});
    }
});

Template.myTemplate.destroyed = function () {
    var instance = this;
    instance._MyClientCollection.remove({});
}
```

Hope this will help...